# Why are my Images not correctly centered?

Tags: tables, graphics, horizontal-alignment, captions

First of all this is my first posting here on tex.stackexchange.com. I'm new to the tex world and I need a little bit of your help.

I am trying to align text relative to a figure. How it should look like in the end:

```
                     an a4 paper
    _______________________________________________
    |              _______________                |
    |              |             |                |
    |       desc   |  a figure   | desc           |
    |              |_____________|                |
    |              _______________                |
    |              |             |                |
    |       desc   |  a figure   | desc           |
    |              |_____________|                |
    |              _______________                |
    |              |             |                |
    |       desc   |  a figure   | desc           |
    |              |_____________|                |
    |              _______________                |
    |              |             |                |
    |       desc   |  a figure   | desc           |
    |              |_____________|                |
    |                0  5  15  30    min          |
    |                                             |
    |            Figure 1: A caption              |
    |                                             |
    |                                             |
    |                                             |
    |_____________________________________________|
```

The descriptions on the right and left vary in length. They also vary in length for the different pictures. The pictures itself would be of the same dimension. However the figures should stay in the middle of the page which means the caption should end up in the horizontal center under the figures.

The figures are in .png format. I am using pdfLatex.

I tried using several approaches to this problem including placing the png's inside an eps with psfrag reference points for the text however like that i did not see the possibility to center align the actual picture since with psfrag the variable length text will be placed inside the picture and also left alignment of the landslide text was not possible. See example 1.

I tried using the floatrow package to place the text as subcaptions left of the figure. It never really worked and I haven't even started to place the text on the right side of the figure.

So I ended up placing the figures inside a table but again I am having problems aligning the pictures to the center. See example 2 for general tabular idea. See example 3 for central alignment of the blots.

The idea of the tabular is to set the width of the first row to .33\textwidth so the image would always start centered of the page [EDIT: logical error -> see comment, i guess it should be .33\textwidth-.5{width of the figure in the second row of the table}]. In the second row is the figure, in the third row is the other description. I dont want the label on the left side to be flushedright because the description of the figure would always follow this format: IP something WB something, so the IP should vertically align.

Example 3 is close but not perfect... and it's very uncomfortable to setup so maybe there is an easier/more simple approach? I thought of something like that but it does not work properly?

The used figures can be found look like that:

png [image: png]

eps [image: eps]

```
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XlMl}
    \multicolumn{2}{p{.333\textwidth}}{}    \\
&Ip EphA2 Wb PTEN   &\includegraphics[width=4cm]{gfx/blots/test.png}    & -- \SI{100}{\kilo\dalton} \\
    \end{tabularx}
```

Example 1

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage[]{auto-pst-pdf}
    \usepackage{psfrag}
    \begin{document}
    \blindtext
    \begin{figure}[bth]
    \footnotesize
    \psfragfig{gfx/test}
    \caption{Some Blots.}
    \label{fig:blot}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

The corresponding test-psfrag.tex contains this code:

```
    \psfrag{1}[br]{IP EphA2 WB EphA2}
    \psfrag{2}[br]{IP NHERF1 WB Cbl}
    \psfrag{3}[br]{IP pPTEN WB pTyr}
    \psfrag{4}[br]{IP EphA2 WB NHERF1}
    \psfrag{a}[bl]{-- \SI{110}{\kilo\dalton}}
    \psfrag{b}[bl]{-- \SI{120}{\kilo\dalton}}
    \psfrag{c}[bl]{-- \SI{130}{\kilo\dalton}}
    \psfrag{d}[bl]{-- \SI{140}{\kilo\dalton}}
    \psfrag{w}[l]{0}
    \psfrag{x}[l]{5}
    \psfrag{y}[l]{15}
    \psfrag{z}[l]{30}
```

Example 2:

```
    \documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \newcolumntype{y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lMX}
    {\begin{tabularx}{.333\textwidth}{Xl}&Ip EphA2 Wb pPTEN\\\end{tabularx}}&\includegraphics[width=4cm]{gfx/blots/test.png}    &-- \SI{110}{\kilo\dalton} \\
    &{\begin{tabularx}{4cm}{yyyy}0 & 5 & 15 & 30\end{tabularx}}             & min \\
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Some Blots}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Example 3:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \newcolumntype{y}{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}X@{}}
    \newcolumntype{M}{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}@{}}
    \begin{document}
    \blindtext
    \begin{figure} 
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l@{ }M@{ }l}
    Ip EphA2 Wb PTEN    &\includegraphics[width=4cm]{gfx/blots/test.png}    & -- \SI{100}{\kilo\dalton} \\
    &{\begin{tabularx}{4cm}{yyyy}
                        0 & 5 & 15 & 30
                        \end{tabularx}}                                     & min \\
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{Some Blots}
    \label{fig:ppf}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Example 4

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{C}{%
    >{\llap\bgroup}c<{\egroup\hskip 1em}%
    @{}>{$\vcenter\bgroup\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup\egroup$}@{}
    >{\hskip 1em\hbox to 0pt\bgroup}c<{\egroup}%
    }%

    \newcommand{\myblotsize}{3cm} %devine blotsize
    \newcommand{\myblot}[1]{\includegraphics[width=\myblotsize]{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{y}{%
    @{}>{$\vcenter\bgroup\centering\bgroup}X<{\egroup\egroup$}@{}
    }%
    \newcommand{\stimulation}[4]{%
            &\begingroup
            \begin{tabularx}{\myblotsize}{yyyy}
            #1 & #2 & #3 & #4\\
            \end{tabularx}\endgroup
            &min
            } %
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\small
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabular}{C}
            IP EphA2 WB EphA2   &\myblot{gfx/test}  &-- 130 kDa \\
            IP EphA2 WB pPTEN   &\myblot{gfx/test}  &-- 54 kDa  \\
            IP EphA2 WB PTEN    &\myblot{gfx/test}  &-- 54 kDA  \\
            IP EphA2 WB Cbl     &\myblot{gfx/test}  &-- 118 kDa \\
            \stimulation{--}{5}{15}{30}\\
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{A caption}
        \label{fig:figure1}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Final code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \newcommand{\myblotsize}{4cm} %Change the width of all blots in the document here
    \newcommand{\myblottextsize}{\scriptsize} %tiny, scriptsize, footnotesize, small, normalsize
    \newlength\widestLeftEntryLength %needed for left alignment of left describtion
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{booktabs} %better management of spaze between rows
    \usepackage{tabularx} %already loaded previously
    \newcolumntype{C}{% blotcolumns centered on blot
            % >{\llap\bgroup}c<{\hskip 1em\egroup} %right alignment of left describtion ATTENTION to \hskip 3.2 in last column
            @{}>{\llap\bgroup\hbox to \widestLeftEntryLength\bgroup}c<{\hss\egroup\egroup}@{}%left alignment of left describtion
            @{}>{$\vcenter\bgroup\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup\egroup$}@{}
            @{}>{\hskip 3.2pt\hbox to 0pt\bgroup}c<{\egroup}@{}%
            }%
    \newcommand{\myblot}[3]{#1&\includegraphics[width=\myblotsize,]{#2}&-- \SI{#3}{\kilo\dalton}\\}
    \newcolumntype{y}{%
            @{}>{$\vcenter\bgroup\centering\bgroup}X<{\egroup\egroup$}@{}
            }%
    \newcommand{\stimulation}[4]{%
            &\begingroup
            \begin{tabularx}{\myblotsize}{yyyy}
            #1 & #2 & #3 & #4\\
            \end{tabularx}\endgroup
            &min
            } %
    \begin{document}
    \centering\rule{\myblotsize}{3pt} %test the horizontal alignment of the following table
    \begin{figure}
        \myblottextsize
        \centering
        \settowidth\widestLeftEntryLength{IP EphA2 WB pPTEN\hskip 3pt} % 
            \begin{tabular}{C}
            \myblot{IP EphA2 WB EphA2}{gfx/test}{130}\addlinespace
            \myblot{IP EphA2 WB pPTEN}{gfx/test}{54}\addlinespace
            \myblot{IP EphA2 WB PTEN}{gfx/test}{54}\addlinespace
            \myblot{IP EphA2 WB Cbl}{gfx/test}{118}
            \stimulation{--}{5}{15}{30}
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{A caption}
        \label{fig:figure1}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: hmm: I guess I made there is an error in my logic. The first row of the table should not be set to .33\textwidth but rather to .33\textwidth-.5{of graphicwidth}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick is to put your graphics in a `\vcenter` box. The rest is just bureaucracy: `\vcenter` requires math mode, and `\hbox` prevents the image from taking the whole line width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}

\newcommand\myincludegraphics[1]{%
  \ensuremath{\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics{#1}}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{3}
  \begin{tabular}{rcl}
    description&\myincludegraphics{gfx/test}&description\\
    description&\myincludegraphics{gfx/test}&description\\
    description&\myincludegraphics{gfx/test}&description\\
    description&\myincludegraphics{gfx/test}&description\\
    &0\hfill 5\hfill\hfill 15\hfill\hfill\hfill 30&min
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A caption}
  \label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: This version deals with descriptions of different lengths, keeping the images horizontally centered no matter what.

The main idea is to put the left descriptions in a `\llap` (so it will stick out to the left, while pretending to `0pt` wide) and the right descriptions in a `\hbox to 0pt` (these will pretend to be `0pt` wide but stick out to the right --- by the way, `\rlap` doesn't work well in this case).

The rest is to make things easy to use. Package `array` allows to you automatically but arbitrary code around your entries using `<` and `>`. Furthermore, it allows you to define new column types. So I put all the `\llap` and `\hbox` magic in the column type `C`, and included the vertical positioning magic in there as well. This should make things easier to use.

Since the middle column type was redefined, the old timeline didn't work anymore, so I used `\multicolumn` to reset the middle column type for the last line back to a simple `c`. While at it, I have packed it all in a macro to save some further typing.  (Maybe we should make it extremely fancy by making LaTeX position the numbers on the timeline automatically? :-))))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{%
      >{\llap\bgroup}c<{\egroup}%
      >{$\vcenter\bgroup\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup\egroup$}
      >{\hbox to 0pt\bgroup}c<{\egroup}%
    }%
\newcommand\timeline[1]{&\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}&min}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{3}
  \begin{tabular}{C}
    description long&\includegraphics{gfx/test}&desc\\
    description&\includegraphics{gfx/test}&description very very extremely long\\
    description&\includegraphics{gfx/test}&desc\\
    description&\includegraphics{gfx/test}&descript\\
    \timeline{0\hfill 5\hfill\hfill 15\hfill\hfill\hfill 30}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A caption}
  \label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{3}
  \begin{tabular}{C}
    description long&\includegraphics{gfx/test}&desc\\
    description very very extremely long&\includegraphics{gfx/test}&desc\\
    description&\includegraphics{gfx/test}&desc\\
    description&\includegraphics{gfx/test}&descript\\
    \timeline{%
      \makebox[0pt][c]{0}\hfill
      \makebox[0pt][c]{5}\hfill\hfill
      \makebox[0pt][c]{15}\hfill\hfill\hfill
      \makebox[0pt][c]{30}}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A caption}
  \label{fig:figure2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

UPDATE 2: Automatic tick-placement (for fun) and fixed intercolumn spacing (for real):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{%
      >{\llap\bgroup}c<{\egroup\hskip 1em}%
      @{}>{$\vcenter\bgroup\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup\egroup$}@{}
      >{\hskip 1em\hbox to 0pt\bgroup}c<{\egroup}%
    }%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\timeline[1]{%
  &\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}\begingroup
  \global\let\do\firstT
  \docsvlist{#1}%
  \endgroup&min%
}
\def\firstT#1{\makebox[0pt][c]{#1}\xdef\previousT{#1}\global\let\do\otherTs}
\def\otherTs#1{%
  \count0=#1\relax \advance\count0-\previousT\relax
  \loop\ifnum\count0>0 \typeout{\the\count0}\advance\count0-1 \hfill\repeat
  \makebox[0pt][c]{#1}\xdef\previousT{#1}%
}    

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{3}
  \begin{tabular}{C}
    description long&\includegraphics{gfx/test}&desc\\
    description&\includegraphics{gfx/test}&description very very extremely long\\
    description&\includegraphics{gfx/test}&desc\\
    description&\includegraphics{gfx/test}&descript\\
    \timeline{0,5,15,30}\\
    \timeline{0,10,20,30}\\
    \timeline{0,20,25,30}\\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A caption}
  \label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{3}
  \begin{tabular}{C}
    description long&\includegraphics{gfx/test}&desc\\
    description very very extremely long&\includegraphics{gfx/test}&description\\
    description&\includegraphics{gfx/test}&desc\\
    description&\includegraphics{gfx/test}&descript\\
    \timeline{0,2,4,6,8,10,20,30}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A caption}
  \label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

UPDATE: left-aligned left description

I don't know how to do this automatically, because one needs to know the width of the widest left description in advance. A semi-automatic solution is to set this length in advance, just before the `tabular` environment --- the column definiton then puts the left description in a `\hbox` of the given width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\newlength\widestLeftEntryLength
\newcolumntype{C}{%
      >{\llap\bgroup\hbox to \widestLeftEntryLength\bgroup}c<{\hss\egroup\egroup\hskip 1em}%
      @{}>{$\vcenter\bgroup\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup\egroup$}@{}
      >{\hskip 1em\hbox to 0pt\bgroup}c<{\egroup}%
    }%

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{3}
  \settowidth\widestLeftEntryLength{description very very extremely long}
  \begin{tabular}{C}
    description long&\includegraphics{gfx/test}&desc\\
    description very very extremely long&\includegraphics{gfx/test}&description\\
    description&\includegraphics{gfx/test}&desc\\
    description&\includegraphics{gfx/test}&descript\\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A caption}
  \label{fig:figure2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When i compile this code i do not get the desired effect... the graphics do not align in the center of the text. It looks like it aligns right. However I really like the \vcenter, it dont have to use the m rowcommand of \tabularx anymore which made me having to deal with setting widths. To clarify: i was working with \vcenter earlier today trying to solve the problem... but i did not know of the \arraystretch command so it didnt really look good ;)

Comment: My mistake... I was checking if the `\hbox` is really important (it is, as we both see:), and I forgot to put it back in. It should be ok now.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the update. There is still the problem that when the descriptions are not of the same length the blots are not aligned in the center anymore. I updated the problem description to clarify the different length of blots.

Comment: Pretty cool new stuff! Thank you!
However the new timeline tweak is not really needed. The numbers under the last blot are not a timeline from left to right although it might seem that way. The minutes indicate how that part of the picture is created. So its basically four numbers that need to be aligned with the darker column in the picture. I added a new Example in the original question so you can see how i changed your code.

And then again, is there a way to let the descriptions on the left be left-aligned?

Comment: `\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[...]{...}}` is just as good as `$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[...]{...}}}$` and surely simpler. Another way is to use the `adjustbox` package with the `export` option and say `\includegraphics[...,valign=M]{...}`

Comment: 1) `adjustbox` package looks great! 2) Is there a way to use `\raisebox` in the `tabular` preamble?

Comment: @egreg Thank you for the adjustbox and \raisebox input, but i when i tried it out as you suggested, the text to the left and right of the picture was not centered with the median but the baseline. Considering this I still prefer the \vcenter method

Comment: @SašoŽivanović You can try with the methods of the `collcell` package.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SašoŽivanović! It now fits my needs perfectly... i added my "final" code in my question and will accept your code as the accepted answer.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović Did you notice that when you place a `\centering\rule{width of the graphic}{3pt}` before the `\begin{figure}` they are not aligned by 2 or 3 points... where might that space come from?

Comment: To solve this last problem I had to hardcode a 3.2pt skip into the right description column `@{}>{\hskip 3.2pt\hbox to 0pt\bgroup}c<{\egroup}@{}%`

Comment: (1) I don't know what is the purpose of your rule, but it almost certainly does not belong *outside* (you have put it before) the `figure` environment. This is a floating environment and can end up on a different page, even, far away from the rule. (2) Since we're really fine-tuning here, it would help if you updated your final example to precisely what you're using right now.

Comment: I just used the rule to verify if the image really is centered on the page -> `\centering\rule{width of my figure}{3pt}` and then a `\begin{figure}[h]`. This gives me a black bar with the same length of my pictures that is centered on the page right on top of the actual image. If our tabular is working correctly the should horizontally align perfect. However they don't if I do not use the `\hskip 3.2pt`

Comment: Ah, I get it! Yes, that's cool. I tried it as well, and I get perfect alignment. In the absence of your code (it's *always* important to post code!) I'd guess that you forgot to put `%` after `\rule{...}{...}`, so the line with the rule contained a space as well, thus the misalignment (a space in the default 10pt config is 3.3333pt). So, the test was faulty, not the figure! :-)

Answer (score 4):

For comparison, this is how one can typeset a similar table in ConTeXt. Horizontally the first column is right flushed, the second is middle aligned, and the third is left flused; vertically, all columns are center aligned (`lohi` keyword).

```
\useMPlibrary[dum] % For dummy figures

\startsetups table:align
  \setupTABLE[frame=off]
  \setupTABLE[column][1][align={flushright,lohi}]
  \setupTABLE[column][2][align={middle,lohi}]
  \setupTABLE[column][3][align={flushleft,lohi}]
\stopsetups


\starttext

\startTABLE[setups={table:align}]
  \NC long desc \NC \externalfigure[dummy][width=3cm, height=3\lineheight] \NC desc \NC \NR
  \NC desc      \NC \externalfigure[dummy][width=3cm, height=3\lineheight] \NC desc \NC \NR
  \NC desc      \NC \externalfigure[dummy][width=3cm, height=3\lineheight] \NC desc \NC \NR
  \NC desc      \NC \externalfigure[dummy][width=3cm, height=3\lineheight] \NC long desc \NC \NR
\stopTABLE

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

The default distance between cells can be changed using the `offset` key.

**EDIT**: If you want the text in the first column to be left flushed, just change the first line of `startsetups` as:

```
\startsetups table:align
  \setupTABLE[frame=off]
  \setupTABLE[column][5][align={flushleft,lohi}]
  \setupTABLE[column][6][align={middle,lohi}]
  \setupTABLE[column][7][align={flushleft,lohi}]
\stopsetups
```

which gives

[image]

If you have long lines, then you can specify that the middle column take only as much space as needed (`width=fit`) and the first and second column split the remaining space equally between them (`width=broad`). For example:

```
\startsetups table:align
  \setupTABLE[frame=off]
  \setupTABLE[column][9][align={flushright,lohi}, width=broad]
  \setupTABLE[column][10][align={middle,lohi},     width=fit,]
  \setupTABLE[column][11][align={flushleft,lohi},  width=broad]
\stopsetups
```

gives (I have shown the page frame using `\showframe` so that it is clear that the table is visually centered on the page)

[image]

Notice that, by default, ConTeXt tries to make both lines in the first cell to be of equal length. If you do not like that, you can add `broad` keyword to the set of `align` keys, and  ConTeXt will make each line as long as possible. For example,

```
\startsetups table:align
  \setupTABLE[frame=off]
  \setupTABLE[column][13][align={flushright,broad,lohi}, width=broad]
  \setupTABLE[column][14][align={middle,lohi},     width=fit,]
  \setupTABLE[column][15][align={flushleft,lohi},  width=broad]
\stopsetups
```

gives

[image]

Comment: What happens when you change the alignment of the left desc to left so the "d"'s would vertically align? I do not have context and I have never worked with it so before I would start getting deeper into it I would appreciate it if you could show me the result.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean. I have added a few more examples to explain what happens with different settings and different line lengths.

Comment: I exactly meant what you anticipated by changing flushright to flushleft. Something similar in Latex this would have decentered the figures. I just was not sure what would happen when using context